# How to capture screen all things in scroll view in Firefox using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, capture

[image]

I have to capture screenshot all things in scroll view, I use keyword Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot and then zoom out but it got only visible screen.

```
Search Transaction Data By Input Date
   Input Text    &{Transaction}[startDate]    ${STARTDATE}
   Input Text    &{Transaction}[endDate]    ${ENDDATE}
   Click Element    &{Transaction}[searchBtn]
   Wait Until Element Is Visible    &{Transaction}[firstTransDate]    timeout=10s
   Firefox Browser Zoom Out    3
   capture page screenshot
```

Appreciate everyone can suggest if there are other ways to capture all things in scroll view.

Comment: Obviously the page layout is making this element to be with that size, even when zooming out. When you do it manually, does it expand to show all elements? If not, why do you expect it to happen when selenium drives the browser.

Comment: @TodorMinakov I have to zoom out because all column have to be show then I will take capture screen. For now I work around by scroll down 7 rows at a time and then capture screen until all rows are capt.